# How to upgrade to the latest Elixir and Phoenix without reinstalling on Windows?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On Windows, there's no convenient package manager like `apt/yum/pacman` on linux, is there any way to upgrade to the latest version of elixir (and Phoenix) without installing from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have package manager in Windows, but you can get one.
Consider Chocolatey. [Install it](https://chocolatey.org/install) and then [get Elixir easily](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-install-elixir-using-chocolatey-on-windows/).

If you don't want to go on these pages type this in `cmd`:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

choco install elixir
```

That's it.

Also you can do it manually- find the folder with elixir and simply replace it with the content of latest zip.

Phoenix Framework will be dependent of the content of mix.exs and you will get it without any issues with `mix deps.get`, since in Elixir ecosystem you won't use "global dependencies", but narrow them to your projects.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it is quit clear. I chose to upgrade manually- find the folder with elixir and simply replace it with the content of latest zip. Simple and effective.